# Interpolating missing data in Python keeping in mind x values

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, missing-data

I need a clarification on what tool to use and how to interpolate missing in Python. Refer to the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

# Create data with missing y values
x = [i for i in range(0, 10)]
y = [i**2 + i**3 for i in range(0, 10)]
y[4] = np.nan
y[7] = np.nan

# Interpolation attempt 1: Use scipy's interpolate.interp1d
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
ynew = f(x)

# Interpolate attempt 2: Use pandas.Series.interpolate
yp = pd.Series(y)
yp = yp.interpolate(limit_direction='both', kind='cubic')

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', x, ynew, '-', x, yp, 'x')

plt.show()
```

Code above yields the following diagram

[image: Graph Plot]

Notice how the interp1d line (as documented) does not handle NaN values.

**My question is: How do I handle NaN values while using the x values as does the scipy's interpolation.interp1d function?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would drop the values associated with NaN values and develop a model for the remaining value pairs and then predict over all `x`. Like so:

```
# Create data with missing y values
x = [i for i in range(0, 10)]
y = [i**2 + i**3 for i in range(0, 10)]
y[4] = np.nan
y[7] = np.nan

# convert to numpy arrays
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

# drop NaNs
idx_finite = np.isfinite(y)
f_finite = interpolate.interp1d(x[idx_finite], y[idx_finite])
ynew_finite = f_finite(x)

# Interpolation attempt 1: Use scipy's interpolate.interp1d
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
ynew = f(x)

# Interpolate attempt 2: Use pandas.Series.interpolate
yp = pd.Series(y)
yp = yp.interpolate(limit_direction='both', kind='cubic')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, 'o',label="true")
ax.plot(x, ynew, '-',label="interp1d")
ax.plot(x, ynew_finite, '--',label="interp1d finite")
ax.plot(x, yp, 'x',label="pandas")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @Eric! Yes, your answer did help. Cheers